# RayLib. How to get color pixel on monitor, don't use WIN API(windows.h)

Tags: c++, opengl, raylib

From the title the question is clear. But raylib.h conflicts with windows.h, so I have no options on how to get the color of a pixel on the monitor.

Comment: You don't. Raylib doesn't provide that kind of functionality.

Comment: Are you only asking about pixels rendered by your application or about general pixels on the monitor even outside the current window? The latter one is probably impossible without using the platform API.